# Azure B2C - Link to source domain in Html Template

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When a user lands on our home page they start on our domain. If they're not logged in, then they're redirected to the Azure B2C login page (which is on a different domain). I've updated the UI by implementing our own [Html Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

I'd like to add a link in the template to an about page on the original domain. I could hard code this to the production url. However, I have different source domains depending on whether I'm working on my local dev machine, testing, staging or production.

Is there a way to refer to the source domain in the template?

I assume one way would be to enable javascript and extract the base url from the `redirect_uri`. But is there anything built-in to Html Templates that will let me do this declaratively (before the page is served)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create some sort of resolver on the front end in just plain HTML. You'll need to use JavaScript to build the URL for the about page on the front end or use separate HTML templates per environment with hard coded links.